# Do elements that have css display:none consume processing power?

Tags: css, semantic-ui

For example, elements that are heavily animated - do they eat on cpu when they are not displayed? Like Semantic-UI's [loader](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/loader.html) - it is rather cpu-hungry when visible.

Answer (score 0):

It will be removed from the display tree which means it won't reside in memory which means it will not consume the micro-miniscule, maybe unmeasureable amount of power it would consume otherwise and this is a really, really bizarre question.